# Trouble with communication with usb B type machine with Matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am using matlab to communicate with several machines.

I am trying to connect with LCC25 (Liquid crystal retarder controller made by Thorlabs) using usb b to usb a cable.

I made a code like this.

```
clear all; clc;
%%
ss=serial('COM7','BaudRate',9600,'DataBits',8);

set(ss,'Parity','none');

set(ss,'Terminator','LF');

fopen(ss);

fprintf(ss,'*idn?');

aa=fscanf(ss)

fclose(ss)
```

Then I get "Warning : Unsuccessful read : A timeout occurred before the Terminator was reached aa=="

Is there any problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also interested in buying the LCC25 and controlling it with MATLAB, so this is very interesting for me and I would love to find out whether it works...

To debug your code, I am wondering what happens when you comment out everything but:

```
ss=serial('COM7','BaudRate',9600,'DataBits',8);
set(ss,'Parity','none');
set(ss,'Terminator','LF');
fopen(ss);
```

Since then we can now if the problem is in establishing the connection itself (which you should not run every time btw!), or in trying to send a command to the device...

If the object creation is succesful, you should see something like this:

```
Serial Port Object : Serial-COM4

   Communication Settings 
      Port:               COM7
      BaudRate:           9600
      Terminator:         'LF'

   Communication State 
      Status:             closed
      RecordStatus:       off

   Read/Write State  
      TransferStatus:     idle
      BytesAvailable:     0
      ValuesReceived:     0
      ValuesSent:         0
```

Then you can try to add run

```
fopen(ss)
fscanf(ss)
```

in a seperate file, and see what the output is. If all of this works, you can start to try sending commands using the 'fprintf' command, but make sure not to run the 'serial' and 'fopen' command every

I am wondering where you obtained the command string '*idn?', did you find this in the help file? The same for the terminator 'LF', are you sure this is the correct terminator to use for the LCC25? When reading the error message you received, I suspect the problem to be that you might need to use other terminators, such as 'CR'.